# True/false : If $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)^2 dx =0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(1/2)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following statement  true/false?

> let $f_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $ be  a  continious  function for each positive integer n.If $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)^2 dx =0$  then $\lim_{n \to \infty}  f_n(1/2)=0$

**My thinking** : I think  this statement is  true

**My attempt** :using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$\left(\int\limits_{0}^{1}f_n(x)\,  \mathrm{d}x\right)^{2}\leq\int\limits_{0}^{1}f_n(x)^{2}\,  \mathrm{d}x.$$
So, $0\leq\int\limits_{0}^{1}f_n(x)^{2}\,  \mathrm{d}x$ $\implies 0\leq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(x)^{2}\,  \mathrm{d}x$.

Therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty}  f_n(1/2)=0$

Comment: It’s not true. I’m also not sure how you’ve drawn the conclusion from $0\leq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{1}f_n(x)^{2}\,  \mathrm{d}x$, which is true for any sequence of continuous real functions with convergent integrals (with or without those integrals going to $0$).

Comment: @TheoBendit $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)^2 dx =0$ $\implies $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)^2 dx \ge0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Consider the hat functions
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} nx - \frac{n}{2} + 1 \hspace{4mm}x\in[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{2}]\\
1+\frac{n}{2} - nx\hspace{4mm}x\in[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}]\\
0 \hspace{23mm}\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Then $f_n(\frac{1}{2}) = 1$ for all $n$ and so $f_n(\frac{1}{2})\not\to 0$ and you can compute that the square of the integral converges to 0. What happens is that for your statement to be true, you would need uniform convergence.

Answer (score 5):

Big Hint: Consider the function that looks like _/\_ on the unit interval and squeeze the middle part till the two angled sides meet.

Comment: I was very tempted to just type _/\\_ as the legendary Didier Piau once did.